# Select from three table on condition basise in mysql

Tags: mysql, select, join

I have three tables

1- Sale

```
Id    Unit    Ref
 1    200    RM-S-2002
 2    300    RM-S-2003
```

2- Rent

```
Id     Unit    Ref
 1      400    RM-R-2009
 2      100    RM-R-2010
```

Fields Structure of both table is same,In Ref middle S represent Sale table and R represent Rent table

3- Details

```
Id      List_Ref 
1        RM-R-2010
2        RM-S-2002
3        RM-S-2003
```

The detail table contains ref of both tables(rent and sale).Now i want to select unit if

If Details.List_ref=Rent.Ref then select Rent.Unit ELSE select Sale.Unit.

Here condition comes before select...How this can be used in query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT d.id, d.list_ref, COALESCE(s.unit, r.unit) unit
  FROM Details d LEFT JOIN Sale s 
    ON d.list_ref = s.ref LEFT JOIN Rent r
    ON d.list_ref = r.ref
```

Sample output:

```
| ID |  LIST_REF | UNIT |
-------------------------
|  1 | RM-R-2010 |  100 |
|  2 | RM-S-2002 |  200 |
|  3 | RM-S-2003 |  300 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c995f/2)** demo

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
  IF(d.List_Ref LIKE '%-S-%', 'Sale', 'Rent') AS Type,
  IF(d.List_Ref LIKE '%-S-%', s.Unit, r.Unit) AS Unit
FROM Details d
  LEFT JOIN Sale s
    ON d.List_Ref = s.Ref
  LEFT JOIN Rent r
    ON d.List_Ref = r.Ref;
```

### Demo

Output

```
| TYPE | UNIT |
---------------
| Rent |  100 |
| Sale |  200 |
| Sale |  300 |
```